# Unit testing for getting random Number in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I have a method in my ts file to create random list as below.

```
list = [];

createItem(index, random_boolean) {
    return { id: index, name: `Item ${index}`, details: `Item ${index} occured`, selected : random_boolean };
}
createRandomItem() {
    const int = parseInt((Math.random() * 100) + '', 10);
    const random_boolean  = Math.random() >= 0.5;
    return this.createItem(int, random_boolean);
  } 

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list.push(this.createRandomItem(i));
}
```

How to write unit test case for createRandomItem() method.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I see where you’re calling `createRandomItem()`, but not where it’s defined. What exactly do you want to test?

Comment: updated the code, please check once

Answer (score 4):

You need to decide what *specifically* you are trying to test. You can probably trust that `Math.random()` has been tested and works as advertised, so you don't need to test that. After that, what are you left with? You can test that given two random numbers, your method does the right thing with them. To do that, you can mock `Math.random()` so it delivers predictable results and then assert the the returned object has the expected properties. If you are using Jasmine, it might look something like:

```
it("should return an object based on the result of Math.random()", function() {
    spyOn(Math, 'random').and.returnValues(0.1, 0.75);
    let t = obj.createRandomItem()
    expect(t).toEqual({ 
        id: 10,
        name: 'Item 10',
        details: 'Item 10 occured',
        selected: true }); 
});
```